# Characteristics of saddle points in stream line charts

Tags: meteorology, synoptic

I am trying to locate saddle points or commonly known as ["col" in synoptic meteorology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Col_(meteorology)). This is "z" in the following figure.[image]

**References**
Here are some of the references regarding this.

a). http://www.zamg.ac.at/docu/Manual/SatManu/main.htm?/docu/Manual/SatManu/CMs/Def/backgr.htm

b). https://www.meted.ucar.edu/labs/synoptic/kinematics/vort_defzones/navmenu.php?tab=1&page=3-0-0&type=flash

**What I want**
1. I would like to know what are the characteristics of these points in terms of divergence, sea level pressure, relative humidity or moisture, etc.
I will be automatically detecting these points from the given characteristics.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Attaching a few references to your question as to what a col is may attract more votes.

Comment: @gansub..as always..thanks for the prompt response. I added a few references.

Comment: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2012GL053097 From this reference surface pressure, wind velocity and heat flux all are a minimum. Remember what I wrote yesterday about curvature and saddle point.

Comment: yes. thank you. I will also have to look into that.

Comment: Mathematically, a saddle point is a minimum amongst one dimension and a maximum along another. The detection thereof should be straight forward. Also characteristics can have different meanings, are you referring to the propagating characteristics of a hyperbolic differential equation, or 'characteristic' as 'property'?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape What OP wants to know is not the detection of saddle points. But at the saddle point what is the value of sea  level pressure, relative humidity, moisture etc. I believe OP is capable of detecting saddle points. But does not know how the values of meteorological parameters behave at that point.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape..gunsub is correct, I just wanted to know the properties of saddle points.

Comment: @Lyndz: Right, I guess I was mainly confused about the formulation of the question. Not a full answer, but: Once you have the flow field, you can at least compute divergence and pressure in analytically, right? Humidity I don't know about.